# `firebase projects:list` doesn't show a specific project

Tags: firebase-tools

I can see this project on the Firebase Console (web), and see the corresponding GCP project when running `gcloud projects list`, but it doesn't show up when running `firebase projects:list`.

There's no `.firebaserc` file anywhere on my filesystem.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the [`firebase: enabled` label](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#project-label-firebase-enabled) was deleted from my GCP project. Manually creating it solved the issue.